# Check my proof: Showing how $\frac{c-a}{d-b}$ compares to $\min(\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d})$ and $\max(\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d})$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, solution-verification, maxima-minima, alternative-proof

This is a follow-up inquiry to a (now-deleted) [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4358230).

Here is my initial query:

> Where is the fraction $\dfrac{c-a}{d-b}$ located with respect to
> $$\text{min}\left(\dfrac{a}{b},\dfrac{c}{d}\right)$$
> and
> $$\text{max}\left(\dfrac{a}{b},\dfrac{c}{d}\right),$$
> assuming $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are all positive integers?

**MY ATTEMPT**

WLOG, we may assume that $b \neq 0$, $d \neq 0$ and $b \neq d$.  Also, WLOG we can assume that
$$\dfrac{a}{b} \leq \dfrac{c}{d}.$$

**IF** the equation
$$\dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{c}{d}$$
holds, then we obtain
$$\dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{c}{d} = \dfrac{a - c}{b - d}$$
since the last relationship holds if and only if
$$\Bigg(a(b - d) = b(a - c)\Bigg) \land \Bigg(c(b - d) = d(a - c)\Bigg)$$
which is true if and only if
$$\Bigg(ad = bc\Bigg) \land \Bigg(ad = bc\Bigg),$$
something which obviously holds.

Now, I claim that **IF** the inequality
$$\dfrac{a}{b} < \dfrac{c}{d}$$
holds, then we have the inequality
$$\text{min}\left(\dfrac{a}{b},\dfrac{c}{d}\right) = \dfrac{a}{b} < \dfrac{c - a}{d - b} < \dfrac{c}{d} = \text{max}\left(\dfrac{a}{b},\dfrac{c}{d}\right).$$

**PROOF**

Since $a$ and $b$ are positive (integers), then
$$0 < \dfrac{a}{b} < \dfrac{c - a}{d - b} < \dfrac{c}{d}.$$

Subtracting and simplifying, we obtain
$$\dfrac{a}{b} - \dfrac{c - a}{d - b} = \dfrac{ad - ab - bc + ab}{b(d - b)} = \dfrac{ad - bc}{b(d - b)} < 0,$$
which means that $b < d$.  This implies that $a < c$.

We may now cross-multiply (without worrying about the signs):
$$\dfrac{a}{b} < \dfrac{c - a}{d - b} \iff ad - ab = a(d - b) < b(c - a) = bc - ab \iff ad < bc$$
which is obviously true;  and
$$\dfrac{c - a}{d - b} < \dfrac{c}{d} \iff cd - ad = d(c - a) < c(d - b) = cd - bc \iff bc < ad,$$
which is **false**.

**CONCLUSION**

> Hence, if the inequality
> $$\dfrac{a}{b} < \dfrac{c}{d}$$
> holds, then what we actually have is the inequality
> $$\text{min}\left(\dfrac{a}{b},\dfrac{c}{d}\right) = \dfrac{a}{b} < \dfrac{c}{d} = \text{max}\left(\dfrac{a}{b},\dfrac{c}{d}\right) < \dfrac{c - a}{d - b}.$$

Here is my final query:

> Is my argument above logically sound?  If not, how can it be mended so as to produce a valid proof?

Comment: Your writeup could be significantly improved. You're saying "If this inequality 1  holds, then we have this other inequality 2. Contradiction. Hence inequality 3." (Which means your first statement is false -> which is exactly what you're trying to do) It would be better to say "If we have inequality (1 and) 2, then there is a contradiction. Hence we must have inequality 3". (which is still incomplete, see next point.)

Comment: Why it's incomplete is because here's still the case of $ (c-a) / d-b) < a/b < c/d$ that you haven't considered. IE There are 3 possibilities to slot in $(c-a)/(d-b)$ into inequality 1, of which you've only eliminated 1 possibility. You have to eliminate another (if at all possible), in order to conclude which one must hold.  (As it turns out, it is not possible. EG Consider $ a = 1, b = 1, c = 2, d = 0.5$.)

Comment: @CalvinLin:  Do you have a counterexample to my conjectured inequality for $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ all **positive integers**?

Comment: Multiply all of my values by 100. (Integer-ality isn't important in this inequality.)

Comment: Before I accept your answer, @CalvinLin, I would just like to verify and confirm:  What is the correct **resulting inequality** for the conditions $c < a, d < b$ and $$\dfrac{a}{b} < \dfrac{c}{d}?$$

Comment: Is it
$$\dfrac{c-a}{d-b} < \dfrac{a}{b} < \dfrac{c}{d}?$$

Comment: If you fill in the gaps in my solution sketch and post your solution (as an answer is fine to me), I can review what you're doing. Otherwise, since I'm not a mind-reader, you could just be guessing where to slot the value (based on a few experimental scenarios), as opposed to knowing for certain why that's the case.

Comment: Okay @CalvinLin!  I actually meant to apply my method in this question to this [recently posted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4358339/28816) to a tangentially related query on odd perfect numbers.  I think you will agree that my approach is flawed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comments for elaborations on the 2 errors in your writeup.

1. Phrasing of the contradiction.
2. Not considering all possible cases to be eliminated.

---

A better way to present your work is  (This is a sketch where you have to fill in the missing details)

1. WLOG $ \dfrac{a}{b} \leq \dfrac{c}{d} $.    So $ bc - ad  \geq 0 $
2. Observe that $ \dfrac{a}{b} - \dfrac{ c-a}{ d - b} = \dfrac{ad - bc } { b(d-b) } $, so

- If $ bc = ad$, then $\dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{c-a}{d-b} $.
- Else If $ d < b $, then  $\dfrac{a}{b} > \dfrac{c-a}{d-b}$.
- Else (IE $ b < d $), then $\dfrac{a}{b} < \dfrac{c-a}{d-b}$.

3. Observe that $ \dfrac{c}{d} - \dfrac{c-a}{d-b} = \dfrac{ ad-bc} { d(d-b) } $, so

- If $ bc = ad$, then $\dfrac{c}{d} = \dfrac{c-a}{d-b} $.
- Else If $ d < b $, then $\dfrac{c}{d} > \dfrac{c-a}{d-b} $.
- Else (IE $ b < d $), then $\dfrac{c}{d} < \dfrac{c-a}{d-b}$.

4. Hence, what is the relevant conclusion? (Depends on how strict you want to be with $ < , \leq, = $ signs in the cases.)

- If $bc = ad$, then $\dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{c}{d} = \dfrac{c-a}{d-b}$.
- Else (If $bc \neq ad$ and $d < b$), then $\dfrac{c-a}{d-b} < \dfrac{a}{b} < \dfrac{c}{d}$.
- Else (If $bc \neq ad$ and $b < d$), then $\dfrac{a}{b} < \dfrac{c}{d} < \dfrac{c-a}{d-b}$.

Note:

- It is possible to have $ b < d $ and $ a > c$, which would lead to $ \frac{c-a}{ d-b } < 0 $.

Comment: Thanks, @CalvinLin.  That was a crystal-clear explanation!

Comment: @ArnieBebita-Dris The conclusion in point 4 isn't correct, because you're missing the case of $ bc = ad$. That's the "depends on how strict you want to be" part.  IE If $ a = b = 1, c = d = 2$, then we have $  b < d$ but still have equality throughout.

Comment: Kindly check my final edits.  Thank you very much for your time, attention, and assistance!  Much appreciated.  =)

Comment: Might want to keep the "else if" phrasing, or be explicit: Case 2 is actually "$bc \neq ad, d < b$", and Case 3 is $"bc \neq ad , b < d $.